# complex equation $\sqrt{8}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Solve $$z^2+2iz-1+2i$$

I tried:

$(z+i)^2-1-1+2i$

$(z+i)^2 = 2-2i$

Which gives me $a^2-b^2 = 2, 2ab = -2, a^2+b^2 = \sqrt(8)$ And this I cannot solve.

Comment: I assume you mean solve $z^2 +2iz-1+2i=0$ (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you mean to solve $z^2+2iz-1+2i=0$)

You were on the right track by completing the square:

$$z^2+2iz-1+2i=(z+i)^2+2i=0$$

From which follows

$$(z+i)^2=-2i\\
z+i=\pm(1-i)\Rightarrow\quad z=\{-1,1-2i\}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$z^2+2 i z-1 = (z+i)^2$$

So the equation for the roots is
$$(z+i)^2=-2 i = 2 \, e^{i 3\pi/2} \implies z+i = \begin{cases} \sqrt{2} \, e^{i 3 \pi/4} \\   \sqrt{2} \, e^{-i \pi/4}\end{cases} $$

The roots are $z=-1$, or $z=1-2 i$.

Answer (score 0):

We want to solve an equation $$z^2+2iz+(2i-1) = 0$$ which is in the correct form for the quadratic formula, so let's use that.  The formula says that $$
\begin{align}
z & = \frac12\left(-2i\pm \sqrt{(2i)^2 - 4(2i-1)}\right)\\
& =\frac12\left(-2i\pm \sqrt{-8i}\right) \\
& = \frac12\left(-2i\pm\sqrt{2i}\sqrt{-4}\right) \tag{$\star$}\\
& = \frac12\left(-2i\pm(1+i)(2i)\right) \\
& = -i\pm (1+i)i\\
& = -i\pm(i-1)\\
& = -1\text{ or }-2i+1
\end{align}
$$

The line $(\star)$ requires a little justification, because the usual rule about  $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt a \sqrt b$ holds only over the positive reals.  But it *is* the case that $\pm\sqrt{ab} = \pm\sqrt a\sqrt b$ for all complex numbers, and that is what we have here. Similarly we can evaluate $\sqrt{2i}$ to either of its two square roots, $\pm(1+i)$, and it doesn't matter which one because the term is prefixed with $\pm$ anyway. We do the same thing with $\sqrt{-4}$, evaluating it to $\pm2i$, and then the $\pm$ sign is absorbed into the $\pm$ that is already there.